# Is there a query which would concatenate deep sub-lists?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my database, I have a list of documents, and each of these documents contains itself another list of documents, the latter being a list of some data with timestamps stored as millis since epoch.

Following is the sample data set:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da5aee33e791547bb418782"),
    "list1" : [
        {
            "document" : {
                "list2" : [
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 100
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 105
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 110
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "document" : {
                "list2" : [
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 101
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 104
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "sub-document" : {
                            "timestamp" : 109
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is it possible to query, for instance, 2 latest documents from all the "second-layer" lists?**

The expected output is:

```
[
    {
        "sub-document": {
            "timestamp": 109
        }
    },
    {
        "sub-document": {
            "timestamp": 110
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is definitely possible, but you have to use aggregation.

Comment: Please brief on what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) twice before you apply [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) and then you can use [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) to get only two elements. You can also run [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote `sub-document` to root level of your result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$list1" },
    { $unwind: "$list1.document.list2" },
    { $sort: { "list1.document.list2.sub-document.timestamp": -1 } },
    { $limit: 2 },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$list1.document.list2.sub-document" } },
    { $sort: { "timestamp": 1 } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LClQuy0EqHX)

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you.